# Unable to connect frontend and backend in MERN app. I was getting a "Network Error" after some changes I am now getting "Cannot GET /api/test/all"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I am creating a role-based authentication MERN app with node.js express as backend and react as frontend. I tried to connect both backend and front following tutorials on https://www.bezkoder.com/react-jwt-auth/.

Here is some code snippets:

App.js file

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import AuthService from "./services/auth.service";
import Login_ from "./components/login.component";
import Register from "./components/register.component";
import MainContent from "./components/main-content.component";
import Profile from "./components/profile.component";
import BoardUser from "./components/board-user.component";
import BoardAdmin from "./components/board-admin.component";



class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.logOut = this.logOut.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      showModeratorBoard: false,
      showAdminBoard: false,
      currentUser: undefined,
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const user = AuthService.getCurrentUser();
    if (user) {
      this.setState({
        currentUser: user,
        showAdminBoard: user.roles.includes("ROLE_ADMIN"),
      });
    }
  }
  logOut() {
    AuthService.logout();
  }
  render() {
    const { currentUser, showAdminBoard } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
          <Link to={"/"} className="navbar-brand">
            Network monitor
          </Link>
          <div className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link to={"/home"} className="nav-link">
                Home
              </Link>
            </li>
            {showAdminBoard && (
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to={"/admin"} className="nav-link">
                  Admin Board
                </Link>
              </li>
            )}
            {currentUser && (
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to={"/user"} className="nav-link">
                  User
                </Link>
              </li>
            )}
          </div>
          {currentUser ? (
            <div className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to={"/profile"} className="nav-link">
                  {currentUser.username}
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a href="/login" className="nav-link" onClick={this.logOut}>
                  LogOut
                </a>
              </li>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to={"/login"} className="nav-link">
                  Login
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to={"/register"} className="nav-link">
                  Sign Up
                </Link>
              </li>
            </div>
          )}
        </nav>
        <div className="container mt-3">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<MainContent/>} />
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login_/>} />
            <Route path="/register" element={<Register/>} />
            <Route exact path="/profile" element={<Profile/>} />
            <Route path="/user" element={<BoardUser/>} />
            <Route path="/admin" element={<BoardAdmin/>} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

here is my index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import { DarkModeContextProvider } from './context/darkModeContext';
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <DarkModeContextProvider>
      <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </DarkModeContextProvider>
);
```

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
//const dbConfig = require("./src/configuration/db.config");
const app = express();
var corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:8081"
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
// parse requests of content-type - application/json
app.use(express.json());
// parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

const db = require("./src/models");
const Role = db.role;
const path = "mongodb+srv://ciaran_barber:barber00@cluster0.2fpgu.mongodb.net/project_db?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
db.mongoose
  .connect(path, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  /*.connect(`mongodb://${dbConfig.HOST}:${dbConfig.PORT}/${dbConfig.DB}`, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
    }) */
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Successfully connect to MongoDB.");
    initial();
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error("Connection error", err);
    process.exit();
  });

// simple route
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "Welcome to Ciaran's web server." });
});

// routes
require("./src/routes/auth.routes")(app);
require("./src/routes/user.routes")(app);

// set port, listen for requests
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});


function initial() {
  Role.estimatedDocumentCount((err, count) => {
    if (!err && count === 0) {
      new Role({
        name: "user"
      }).save(err => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("error", err);
        }
        console.log("added 'user' to roles collection");
      });
      new Role({
        name: "admin"
      }).save(err => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("error", err);
        }
        console.log("added 'admin' to roles collection");
      });
    }
  });
}
```

package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "final_year_project_b00759858",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.6.2",
    "@mui/material": "^5.6.2",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.10.0",
    "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin": "^0.5.3",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^5.5.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.1.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "babel-jest": "^27.4.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.3.8",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^10.0.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "bfj": "^7.0.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "browserslist": "^4.18.1",
    "camelcase": "^6.2.1",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "^2.4.0",
    "concurrently": "^7.1.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "css-loader": "^6.5.1",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^7.0.1",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.1",
    "express": "^4.18.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "fs-extra": "^10.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.4.3",
    "jest-resolve": "^27.4.2",
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "^1.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "koala": "^1.0.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.4.5",
    "mongoose": "^6.3.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.16",
    "postcss": "^8.4.4",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^5.0.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "postcss-normalize": "^10.0.1",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^7.0.1",
    "prompts": "^2.4.2",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^3.0.0",
    "react-dev-utils": "^12.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-refresh": "^0.11.0",
    "react-router": "^6.3.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-validation": "^3.0.7",
    "resolve": "^1.20.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.50.1",
    "semver": "^7.3.5",
    "source-map-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.2",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.2.5",
    "validator": "^13.7.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^4.0.2",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^6.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/src"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!src/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "react-app-polyfill/jsdom"
    ],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/babelTransform.js",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx)$",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "web.ts",
      "ts",
      "web.tsx",
      "tsx",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ],
    "watchPlugins": [
      "jest-watch-typeahead/filename",
      "jest-watch-typeahead/testname"
    ],
    "resetMocks": true
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "sass-loader": "^12.6.0",
    "webpack": "^5.72.0"
  }
}
```

EDIT:
Also if I `"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:8080/",` to package.json file I get this error:

"Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/test/all from localhost:8081 to http://127.0.0.1:8080/.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED)."

Comment: I am not sure your question is clear. please use this guideline: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Attach the express server file, and your package.json. You should be serving the react app on port 3000 by default, it's weird you have 8081...

Comment: i have added these now @CesarePolonara

Comment: That's not clear what you are doing, why you have both react and express deps in a unique package.json ? Client JS will have to be bundled, while server files don't. You need to separate server and client, then you can use "proxy" entry in the client package.json, to avoid CORS issues during development.

Comment: @CesarePolonara - Thanks for helping me out. I managed to get it working by adding a script for server ("server": "nodemon server.js"), one for client ("client": "npm start") and one for dev to run both concurrently ("dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""). Not sure if this is what you were hinting at.

Comment: You should split client and server with separate dependencies / node_modules / package.json. You find a lot of examples online of how to setup a react/express repository correctly.  I suggest you to use create-react-app as well, since it makes things easier for beginners ( and not only for them ) .